# react-slick slickNext method - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slider' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I'm using the react-slick carousel with the Green Sock animation tool, and I've gotten the slider and animations to work. The problem now is calling slickNext method when the animation ends on a slide. I keep getting this error whether I use refs or not (but my "test" is working and showing in the console). The github documentation for this method is a bit meager and confusing, and I haven't found any similar situations to mine that I can use as reference. How can I access this method?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import AnimationStory1 from "../../components/Animation/AnimationStory1";
import AnimationStory2 from "../../components/Animation/AnimationStory2";
import AnimationStory3 from "../../components/Animation/AnimationStory3";
var Slider = require("react-slick");

export default class IntroStory extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  nextSlide () {
    console.log("test");
    this.refs.slider.slickNext();
  }

  render () {
//These are GreenSock animation instances
    var timeline1 = new TimelineLite({onComplete: this.nextSlide});
    var timeline2 = new TimelineLite();
    var timeline3 = new TimelineLite();

//These are settings for the react-slick slider
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
//      slide: true,
      swipe: true,
      accessibility: true,
      arrows: false,
      beforeChange: function () {
        timeline1.restart();
        timeline2.restart();
        timeline3.restart();
      }
    };

    return <div>
      <Helmet title="Welcome to We Vote" />
      <div className="container-fluid well u-gutter__top--small fluff-full1 intro-story">
        <Slider ref="slider" {...settings}>
          <div key={1}><AnimationStory1 timeline1={timeline1}/></div>
          <div key={2}><AnimationStory2 timeline2={timeline2}/></div>
          <div key={3}><AnimationStory3 timeline3={timeline3}/></div>
          <div key={4}><p>This will be an image</p></div>
         </Slider>
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your method to ensure the context `this` is taken care of:

```
 render () {
//These are GreenSock animation instances
    var timeline1 = new TimelineLite({onComplete: this.nextSlide.bind(this)});
    var timeline2 = new TimelineLite();
    var timeline3 = new TimelineLite();
```

When you just pass, 
`var timeline1 = new TimelineLite({onComplete:  this.nextSlide})`
you are effectively just concentrating on passing the callback, but the method `nextSlide` uses the `this` context and when the callback is invoked, you need to ensure that `this` has the `refs` in them to invoke the `slider`. [Read more here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/)